# Strong parameters JSON API rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working to an REST API in Rails 4.2 and I want to respect [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org) format. My params are like this:

```
{
  "data":{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "this is title",
      "description": "This is description"
    }
}
```

I tried to write a method for strong params like this:

```
def article_params
    params.require(:data).permit(:id, attributes: [:title, :description])
end
```

but when I try to do `Article.update_attributes(article_params)` it says `title and description parameters not permitted` [My Article model has title and description]. Can you help me?

Comment: Try this `params.require(:data).permit(:id, :title, :description)`

Comment: I tried now. Same error :( I can't figure out where is the problem...

Comment: @Pavan check the [JSONAPI spec](http://jsonapi.org/) attributes are supposed to be wrapped in an attriubtes hash.

Comment: @max Thanks. Just putting my head in the content which I don't know :)

Comment: @max, have you any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Dealing with JSONAPI params is only slightly different than dealing with the usual Rails params hashes:

```
class ArticlesController < ApiController

  before_filter :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /api/v1/articles
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_attributes)
    # ...
  end

  # PATCH /api/v1/articles/:id
  def update
     @article.update(article_attributes)
     # ...
  end

  # ...

  private 

  def set_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def article_attributes
    params.require(:data)
          .require(:attributes)
          .permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

First thing you should notice here is that we are not even using `params[:data][:id]` key from the JSON data at all since the ID is available from the request url (`params[:id]`). If you follow RESTful patterns chances are that you never will need to use the `params[:data][:id]` parameter.

In `article_attributes` we are using nested require calls because we want Rails to raise an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` error unless the provided JSON data confirms to the JSON API spec. The vanilla Rails default is to rescue with a 400 Bad Request response - [RailsAPI](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) will return 422 and an JSON error object if it is properly set up for JSONAPI which is what we want.

Comment: On a project I am working on now I also check in a before action that the data[:type] param matches the correct type and return a 422 if it does not.

Comment: Should it be `allow` or `permit` ? I tried allow and rails said there was no such method called allow.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the best way to achieve that now is :

added

```
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

to your Gemfile

and this on your controller

```
ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params)
```

bonus handle dash for you.

```
params = { "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Bucket List",
      "created-by": "John Doe"
    },
    "type": "todos"
  }
}
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(params)
ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params)
=> {:title=>"Bucket List", :created_by=>"John Doe"}
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not whitelist the parameters. Which is the topic of the question.

Comment: You can pass `only` option as follows: `ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(params, only: [:title, :content, :author])`. See more about it in ams [deserialization](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/deserialization.md) guide section. You can even use `except` option if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a json:api library which provides deserialization capabilities, such as http://jsonapi-rb.org, so that you do not have to deal with the json:api format directly. In that context, your example would read:

```
 class ArticlesController < ApiController
   deserializable_resource :article, only: [:create, :update]

   def article_params
     params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
   end

   # ...
 end
```

Comment: Can you get the link of the documentation or online code for where exactly `ApiController ` come from?